# How to add a column in Symfony default query builder

Tags: php, symfony

I am new in Symfony, and I have a problem with an existing application I maintain.

In one of the repositories, there's is a method, that selecting the failed transactions, and the related payment.

Now, they have asked me, to allow filter the transactions, based on the total amount of failed transactions which could be either `1` failed transaction or `2`.

What I am trying to do in the query builder, is something like that:

```
$this
    ->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->join('t.payment', 'p')
    ->leftJoin( Transaction::class, 'tr', Query\Exprt\Join::WITH, 'p.id = tr.payment')
    ->groupBy('tr.id');
```

Until that point everything is fine. The query is executed normally, and I can see the transactions I need.

Now the problem is that I cannot use the following statement:

```
$this
    ->createQueryBuilder('t')
    // This is the column I need to insert
    ->addSelect('COUNT(tr.id) AS TotalRecords')
    ->join('t.payment', 'p')
    ->leftJoin( Transaction::class, 'tr', Query\Exprt\Join::WITH, 'p.id = tr.payment')
    ->groupBy('tr.id');
```

Because the output looks like that:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => Transaction {#1221 ▶}
    "TotalRecords" => "1"  <- This is the total transactions number I need
  ]
]
```

Instead of the output above, I need to have the `TotalRecords` inside the `Transaction` Object.

So, Is there a way to achieve that with the query builder? Do you think I do something wrong?

Comment: Out of the box, Doctrine does not do well when adding custom fields to an entity or with calculated fields in general.  You should take a look at the [native functionality](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql) which basically allows you to custom map a given query to a given entity.  It works well in simple cases.

Comment: Thank you very much @Cerad. But I can't do that change as the project is not 100% mine. They just asked me to perform that unique change :(. Anyway, thank you very much !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just loop over your result set and set TotalRecords on all Transaction objects... and return an array of Transactions, as you probably have hoped. The overhead is minimal but the standard doctrine hydration isn't smart enough

```
// the following is your query:
$qb = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(tr.id) AS TotalRecords')
    ->join('t.payment', 'p')
    ->leftJoin( Transaction::class, 'tr', Query\Exprt\Join::WITH, 'p.id = tr.payment')
    ->groupBy('tr.id');

// fetch the results, and instead of straight returning them, "merge"
$results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
$return = [];
foreach($result as $row) {
    $row[0]->totalCount = $row['TotalCount'];
    $return[] = $row[0];
}
return $return; // <-- now an array of Transaction
```

you also could just not use `addSelect` but instead [`having`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#line-number-5775ab09aefa638b14c776a733b4b61d2e324b74-68) and just use the number of transactions you want to filter by, as a parameter (unless the filtering is done later, in which case that approach won't work)